Function defined in an `api.js` file stored in the public folder, but when that function is called within component, error claims it is not defined
I'm trying to call a fetchAPI function that is defined in my api.js file, but am continually receiving the error that it is undefined.
Below is the code within the api.js file (note: the api code was not written by me, but was received as a resource for the exercise):
const seededRandom = function (seed) {
    var m = 2 ** 35 - 31;
    var a = 185852;
    var s = seed % m;
    return function () {
        return (s = s * a % m) / m;
    };
}

const fetchAPI = function (date) {
    if (!(date instanceof Date)) {
        date = new Date(date);
    };

    let result = [];
    let random = seededRandom(date.getDate());

    for (let i = 17; i <= 23; i++) {
        if (random() < 0.5) {
            result.push(i + ':00');
        }
        if (random() < 0.5) {
            result.push(i + ':30');
        }
    }
    return result;
};
const submitAPI = function (formData) {
    return true;
};

Next is the tag I created in the index.html file:
<body>
  <script src="api.js"></script>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

and lastly the attempted call of the function in my component (a React component utilizing useFormik):
export function BookingForm() {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            guests: '',
            date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
            time: 'Select Time',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            occasion: 'Occasion',
            otherInfo: '',
            confirmButton: false,
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
            guests:
                Yup.number()
                    .positive('Must be a positive number')
                    .min(1, 'There must be at least one guest')
                    .max(25, 'Our maximum party size is 25, for larger groups, please contact us directly to book a private event')
                    .required('Please enter the number of guests.'),
            date: Yup.date()
                .test(
                    'date',
                    'The date you selected has already passed.',
                    function (date) { return new Date(date) >= new Date(); }
                )
                .required('Required'),
            time: Yup.string()
                .notOneOf(['Select Time'], 'Please select one of our available time slots.')
                .required('Please select one of our available time slots.'),
            firstName: Yup.string().required('Required').trim(),
            lastName: Yup.string().required('Required').trim(),
            email: Yup.string().email('Please enter a valid email address').required('Required').trim(),
            phone: Yup.string()
                .required('Required')
                .matches(/^[0-9]{10}$/, 'Please enter a valid phone number')
                .min(10, 'Please enter a valid phone number'),
            confirmButton: Yup.boolean().oneOf([true], 'You must confirm the information above is accurate to submit your booking'),
        }),
        onSubmit:
            (values, { resetForm }) => {
                if (formik.isValid) {
                    console.log('Form submitted:', values);
                    alert('Your reservation has been submitted! We will send you a confirmation email shortly.');
                    resetForm();
                } else {
                    alert('Please fill out all required fields before submitting your reservation.');
                }
            }
    });

    const availability = fetchAPI(formik.values.date);

The api.js file is stored within the public folder and referenced in a script tag in the index.html file. I have tried both the standalone function call and placing it inside a useEffect hook.

it seems like react code runs before the api.js load

This was helpful thank you!

There were a few things wrong with my code.
First, as mentioned by @Jatin Parmer in the comments, the api file needed to be loaded prior to the React code, so I changed the placement of the <script> tag to be earlier, and in the <head> instead of in the body.
Second, the sample code I was provided in the api was not functional. The functions were declared with a const key word which is not correct, so I edited their code in my own version of the file using var instead to override that.
Lastly, because the fetchAPI was a global function that I was trying to access, I needed to preface it with window.
Once I made these three changes, and restarted npm, it was functioning properly.
